# Get key of minimum value in a Hashtable

Tags: java, hash

I have a Hashtable in java like below and I'm trying to get the key that has the minimum value. Obviously I can iterate through all the elements to find it but is there an easier way to do it?

```
Hashtable<Object, Integer> hash= new Hashtable<Object, Integer>();
```

Comment: Given that your keys are of type `Object` what's your definition of "minimum value?"

Comment: @noahz The `Integer` is the value.

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005053/key-for-maximum-value-in-hashtable

Comment: Sorry, misread. Basically, you want the `Map.Entry` that has the minimum value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>Using a Hashtable, no. But you could instead use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).</s>

> A Red-Black tree based [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation. The map is sorted
>   according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator
>   provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

It has a method [`firstKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#firstKey%28%29) which provides the exact functionality you want.

---

Grr, values, not keys. No, then you will need to iterate.

I'd say in that case you should use a separate Map (Multimap?) to store the reverse association.

```
Map<Object, Integer> hash= new Hashtable<Object, Integer>();
SortedSetMultimap<Integer, Object> reverse = TreeMultimap.create();
```

whenever you put `key`, `value` something into `hash`, also put `value`, `key` into `reverse`.
then retrieve the lowest value using `reverse.keySet().first()`

(this solution requires [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/))

Comment: +0 I missed that the OP is looking for the minimum value not key.

Comment: Unless you provide a custom comparator, as the Javadoc says.

Comment: He is not interested in KEY ordering but VALUE ordering

Comment: Missed that the first time, sorry.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd.. What will happen if we have duplicate values?? Can you please explain??

Comment: That's why we use a Multimap. A Multimap maps a single key to multiple values.

Comment: Of course you can implement a Multimap yourself, without using Guava. Basically it's a Map from a single value to a collection of values. But it's a pain in the ass to do it yourself, and the Guava Multimaps work great.

Comment: Multimaps are overkill here -- in fact, I'm not even sure they're useful at all.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating yourself you can use library function [Collections.min(Collection,Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) over `entrySet()`.

**SAMPLE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map.put("A", 1);
    map.put("B", 2);
    map.put("C", 3);

    System.out.println( 

    Collections.min(map.entrySet(), new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {

            return o1.getValue().intValue() - o2.getValue().intValue();

        }})

        .getKey()


    );
}
```

Comment: This will just give him the minimal VALUE. He wants the KEY associated with the minimal value.

Comment: P.S. Of course this is equivalent to iterating and may be less readable in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest way to do it is in fact iterating over the elements. If the Hashtable name is hash:

```
Object minObj= null;
int min= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> x: hash.entrySet()){
    if(x.getValue() < min){
            min= x.getValue();
            minObj= x.getKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has written there that he can iterate, but looking for a better way.

Comment: I am OP ;). This is just to confirm that there is no better way.

Comment: @MinaHany.. Probably you would like Suzan's answer above... It is easier, quite clear, and you don't have to do any iteration.. Apart, of course iteration is the last choice..

Answer (score 0):

Minimum value can be findout in this way as well,

```
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    h.put(10, "aaa");
    h.put(1, "aab");
    h.put(12, "aabwqkjdg");

    Set set = h.keySet();

    TreeSet treeSet= new TreeSet();
    treeSet.addAll(set);

    System.out.println("Last :"+treeSet.first());
```

I just took example of keys as integer.

Comment: you are getting the `keySet()` here which is not what the OP wants. also if you want to order your keys then why not just start with a `TreeMap` instead of creating a `Hashtable` then pour keys into `TreeSet`?