# How to Get All the Min Values from a Hash Map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Hash Map with Keys objects of type Request and Values of type Integer. I use the following code to iterate through the map and get ALL the minimum values and then add their keys to a list. I emphasize to ALL because the keys are unique but the values can be duplicate, therefore there may be more than one map elements with the minimum value.

However, this code gives me only a single such element, that is, the first that it finds through the iteration, even though I know there are more. For example, let us say that the map has the following requests - i.e. keys (I give the request IDs): 3 | 5 | 2 and their respective values are: 8 | 4 | 4. Thus, at this example we have two minimum elements, that is, two elements that share the minimum value, ID 5 and ID 2, both with value 4. The code will add to my list only the element with ID 5, that is, the first one of them.

I have to note that there is a similar thread ([Key for maximum value in Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005053/key-for-maximum-value-in-hashtable)) but the provided solution does not work in my case.

Here is the code:

```
 Entry<Request, Integer> min = null;

 List<Request> minKeyList = new ArrayList<Request>();

 for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry : this.map.entrySet()) {

      if (min == null || min.getValue() > map.getValue()) {

           min = entry;
           minKeyList.add(entry.getKey());

      }
```

Any suggestion or explanation why this is happenning would be appreciated.

EDIT: New approach

Well, I found a solution. It is not elegant, but it works. Here is the code.

```
    // list for finding the min value
    List<Integer> minValList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // List for keeping the keys of the elements with the min value
    List<Request> minKeyList = new ArrayList<Request>();

    // scan the map and put the values to the value list
    for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry : this.map.entrySet()) {

        minValList.add(entry.getValue());

    }

    // scan the map   
    for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry: this.map.entrySet()) {

        // find the min value
        if(entry.getValue() == Collections.min(minValList)) {

            // add the keys of the elements with the min value at the keyList
            minKeyList.add(entry.getKey());

       }

    }
```

Comment: @MatthiasMeid:  The change from > to >= works! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: See my updated answer and my comment on Padrus's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079338/how-to-get-all-the-min-values-from-a-hash-map-in-java#comment22953586_16079659; there was a mistake in my first approach - and please remember to mark an answer as the accepted answer as soon as your problem is solved.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid: Thank you for your update. I test both suggested solutions, but I still have some problems. I will do a little bit more testing on the code and I will post an update, either with the solution (hopefully) or with the resulted behavior of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you a *two-step process*:

1. Find the minimum, store in `min`
2. Find all elements with a value equal to `min`

Here is a code sample:

```
// find minimum first
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry : this.map.entrySet()) {
    min = Math.min(min, map.getValue())
}

// add all elements that have a value equal to min
List<Request> minKeyList = new ArrayList<Request>();
for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry : this.map.entrySet()) {
    if(min.getValue() == min) {
        minKeyList.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Both of your answers work fine, only a minor modification of the rest of my code was needed. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As Matthias Meid said, you have to use a `>=` instead of a `>` .

Also, if think you should had something like this or you minKeyList will contain all the value `min` has had.

```
if(min == null || min.getValue() >= map.getValue()) {
    if(min == null || min.getValue() > map.getValue()){
        min = entry;
        minKeyList.clear();
    }
    minKeyList.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

**Edit : Tested code**

I tested this method with some sample code and it seems to work correctly.

Here is the code I used to test it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(7, 12);
    map.put(3, 3);
    map.put(1, 10);
    map.put(4, 12);
    map.put(6, 3);
    map.put(8, 3);
    map.put(9, 13);
    Entry<Integer, Integer> min = null;
    List<Integer> minKeyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        if (min == null || min.getValue() >= entry.getValue()) {
            if(min == null || min.getValue() > entry.getValue()){
                min = entry;
                minKeyList.clear();
            }
            minKeyList.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    for (Integer integer : minKeyList) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

To ease my test, keys and values are both integers but it shouldn't change anything.

No here is my output :

```
3
6
8
```

It seems right to me.
If this doesn't help, try posting a little bit more of your code.

Comment: My first approach was not good enough, I changed it to a two-step process, which I think is needed to avoid getting false results because of local minima. Suppose you have a list like `5, 5, 4, 4`. The code I posted in the first place would use both `5` and `4` as a minimum. Updated my answer.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I added the 
`if(min.getValue() > map.getValue()){
        minKeyList.clear();
 }`

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to emphasize using `>=` instead of `>` as I did first is not good enough, not criticizing your code.

Comment: @Padrus: Thank you for your answer. I used your approach, but it does not work as expected. Here is an example of the results: I have these elements in the map: 7 | 3 | 1 with values 12 | 12 | 10. The list contains all three elements, while it should add the first two and then, when it finds the third which has a lower value, delete them and add the third one. That is, at the end the list should contain only the element 1 since this has the min value (10). I have to say that I print the values of the elements as well as the list after the outer if-statement block ends.

Comment: @Padrus: If instead of an ArrayList I used a LinkedList I could remove the keys with value 12 and keep only the key with value 10, referring to the previous example, right? I think so, but I am not sure (I am new in programming in general and in Java in particular and not very familiar with all the data structures and their operations). I will try that anyway and post an update.

Comment: Weird, I have some time so I'll quickly try it. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Padrus: I haven't check your edited answer yet, I will check it and I will reply to you if it works also to my code as expected. In the meanwhile, I found a workaround for my problem, probably not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: @Padrus: Sorry for the late response. Both of your answers work fine, only a minor modification of the rest of my code was needed. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid multiple loops by using 2 lists/sets e.g.

Before loop starts

```
    Set setExisting = new HashSet();
    Map keyMap = new HashMap();
    // find minimum first
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`enter code here`
    for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry : this.map.entrySet()) {
    Set newSet= new HashSet<String>();
        min = Math.min(min, map.getValue());
        newSet.add(map.getValue(min));
        keyMap.put(min,newSet);
        if (min==map.getValue()){
           setExisting = (Set) keyMap.get(newSet);
           setExisting.add(map.getValue(min));
           keyMap.put(min,setExisting);
         }
  }

  // We will NOT need the below loop in that case
  // add all elements that have a value equal to min
  List<Request> minKeyList = new ArrayList<Request>();
  for(Entry<Request, Integer> entry : this.map.entrySet()) {
    if(min.getValue() == min) {
        minKeyList.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```